# Android Asynchronous HTTP Requests

Tags: php, android

I'm new to Android and have been searching the internet trying to find a way to post some data to php. All I want to do is send one string. Using what I could find I came up with the following

Here is what I have

```
package uk..........;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the About button */ 
    public void openAbout(View view) {     
        // Do something in response to button }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayAbout.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Graph button */ 
    public void openGraph(View view) {     
        // Do something in response to button }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayGraph.class); 
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Test button */ 
    public void openTest(View view) {     
        // Do something in response to button }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayTest.class); 
        startActivity(intent);  
    }

    public void sendData(View v) {

        new MyAsyncTask().execute("Hello World");
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://......../receiver.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I know the php code works as I've tried it using an html form, but when I run this the app crashes and closes down. There are no errors in the code, and at the moment I'm trying to get the emulator in Eclipse to work but with no joy so that doesn't help.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Did you add internet permission to the manifest?:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing, it works now! Thanks Tobiel, a massive help!

Answer (score 0):

Without the stacktrace is hard to say where the error is, but try using the `Activity` `Context` instead of the `Application` `Context` like this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```